# Display RSS Feed on front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, vue.js

I want to display a series of articles from this Google Alert RSS Feed (https://www.google.ie/alerts/feeds/10663948362751557705/4511034072220974544) on my Vue.js application.

I have created a "Feed.vue" component and wish to display the feed on "App.vue". My backend is Express.js. First off, am I even doing this correct? I got this working in Javascript but I want to use Vue.js as my front end.

For some reason I am getting this error regarding my title: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdMP5.png)

My code:

Feed.vue

```
 <template>
   <li>
      {{feed.title}}
   </li>
</template>

<script>
   export default {
      props: ["feed"]
   }
</script>
```

App.vue

```
    <template>
  <div id="app">
<Feed></Feed>
   <ul>
      <feed v-for="feed in feeds" :feed="feed" :key="feed.title"></feed>
   </ul>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
import io from 'socket.io-client'
   import Feed from './components/Feed.vue'
   export default {
      components: {
         Feed
      },
      data () {
         return {
            feeds: []
         }
      },
      mounted() {
         this.subscribeToFeed();
      },
      methods: {
         subscribeToFeed() {
            const socket = io();
            socket.on('feed', data => {
               data.feed.entries().forEach(feed => {
                  this.feeds.push(feed);
               });
            });
         }
      }
   }
</script>
```

Where do I place this in my code?

```
   const socket = io();
    socket.on('feed', data => {
      for (const [i, item] of data.feed.entries()) {
        let itemContainer = $('<span></span>')
          .addClass('feed__content')
          .append(`<p>${i + 1}) ${item.title}<p>`)
          .append(`<p>${item.link}</p>`)
          .appendTo('.feed');
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This error happen, because you declared the `Feed` component without properties in line 3 in `App.vue`.

Your code is that way:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Feed></Feed> <!-- YOU NEED REMOVE THIS LINE -->
    <ul>
      <feed v-for="feed in feeds" :feed="feed" :key="feed.title"></feed>
     </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

The correct code is:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <ul>
      <feed v-for="feed in feeds" :feed="feed" :key="feed.title"></feed>
     </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you. Also where do i place the connection to the socket code? I have done it in js but want to convert it to vue. I have edited my post (see above) :)

Comment: Nowhere, Vue don't recommend you handle the DOM. The first code was correct.

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? Please accept this answer and close the question. This will help others people.